# Need to reorder XML /Xdocument based off element attribute

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am trying to reorder the XML based off the DisplayOrder. My XML is:

```
<ArrayOfCableItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CableItem>
    <ItemID>6</ItemID>
    <CableID>146242</CableID>
    <FabID></FabID>
    <Description>C</Description>
    <ItemValue></ItemValue>
    <Unit/>
    <ItemComment/>
    <Level>MET-JBOX J1</Level>
    <Jack/>
    <Type>Marker</Type>
    <CableType>FreeForm</CableType>
    <DisplayOrder>3</DisplayOrder>
  </CableItem>
  <CableItem>
    <ItemID>540867</ItemID>
    <CableID>146242</CableID>
    <FabID>1398</FabID>
    <Description>Routing</Description>
    <ItemValue>27</ItemValue>
    <ItemComment/>
    <Type>Routing</Type>
    <DisplayOrder>2</DisplayOrder>
  </CableItem>
</ArrayOfCableItem>
```

I have tried the following

```
XDocument output = new XDocument(new XElement("ArrayOfCableItem",
    from s in xdoc.Root.Elements()
    orderby Convert.ToInt32(s.Attribute("DisplayOrder").Value)
    select s));
```

I have tried this, I am at a loss

```
 var reordered = xdoc
     .Element("ArrayOfCableItem")
     .Elements("CableItem")
     .OrderBy(DO => Convert.ToInt32(DO.Attribute("DisplayOrder")));
 XDocument doc2 = new XDocument(new XElement("ArrayOfCableItem"), reordered);
```

these blow up saying that the addition operation may result in a malformed xml

Comment: You've provided two things you've tried, but you haven't told us what the results of either of them were.

Answer (score 1):

Try as said below, it is working.

Look into the comments for details.

```
         //LOAD THE XML 
         XDocument srcTree = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\<<USERID>>\\Desktop\\SampleXML.xml");

         //CREATE NEW XML OUTPUT
         XDocument doc = new XDocument(    
                         //ROOT ELEMENT       
                         new XElement("ArrayOfCableItem",
                         //FROM ALL ELEMENTS
                         from el in srcTree.Element("ArrayOfCableItem").Elements()
                         //ORDER BY "DISPLAYORDER" WHICH IS DESCENDANT ELEMENT
                         orderby (string)el.Descendants("DisplayOrder").First()  
                         //SELECT THE ELEMENTS ORDERED
                         select el ));

         //PRINT NEW XML IN CONSOLE
         Console.WriteLine(doc);
```